# The caption inside the img element is not getting affected by the id

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align the caption differently to the image but it is stuck with the image and I am unable to alter its features even though it has a separate id inside its element. The id='img-caption' does not seem to affect the 'caption' element.

HTML

```
<main id='main'>
<h1>Agha Hassan Abedi</h1>
<h2 id='title'>
  A tribute to Agha Sahib</h2>
  <div id='img-div'><img id='img' src='https://www.pakpedia.pk/files/Image/jpg/2c6ccb0373586eefb0f441936770a47a.jpg'></img><caption id='img-caption'>Picture of Agha Hassan Abedi</caption>
  </div>
<h3 id'tribute-info'>Agha Hasan Abedi, was a Pakistani banker and philanthropist. Abedi founded Bank of Credit and Commerce International in 1972. Abedi underwent a heart transplant operation in 1988, and died of a heart attack on 5 August 1995 in Karachi.</h3>
<a id-'tribute-link' target='_blank' href='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agha_Hasan_Abedi'>More Info</a>
</main>
```

CSS

```
#main {
  background-color: #eee;
}

#title {
  background-color: lightgray;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
#img-div {
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align:left;
}
#img-caption {
  background-color: gray;
}

#img {
  align: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  #position: absolute;
  #center: 0px;
}

h1 {
  color: gray;
  font-family: Times New Roman;
  text-align: center;
}
```

https://codepen.io/wajieraja/pen/gOaeGvm

Comment: Could you try telling us what you're trying to do, exactly? Also, could I interest you in `<figure>` and `<figcaption>`? Looks like the best candidate for your case.

Comment: Ia m trying to position the caption differently to the image. Right now it is stuck to the photo.

Answer (score 1):

The [caption element](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_caption.asp) is used inside a table. If you want to use it with an image, I suggest you to wrap your image inside a figure element and to add a figcaption element.
In your case it can't be something like this :

```css
#main {
  background-color: #eee;
  font: calibri;
}

#title {
  background-color: lightgray;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
#img-div {
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align:left;
}
#img-caption {
  background-color: gray;
}

#img {
  align: center;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  #position: absolute;
  #center: 0px;
}

h1 {
  color: gray;
  font-family: Times New Roman;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<main id='main'>
<h1>Agha Hassan Abedi</h1>
<h2 id='title'>
  A tribute to Agha Sahib</h2>
  <figure id='img-div'><img id='img' src='https://www.pakpedia.pk/files/Image/jpg/2c6ccb0373586eefb0f441936770a47a.jpg'><figcaption id='img-caption'>Picture of Agha Hassan Abedi</figcaption>
  </figure>
<h3 id'tribute-info'>Agha Hasan Abedi, was a Pakistani banker and philanthropist. Abedi founded Bank of Credit and Commerce International in 1972. Abedi underwent a heart transplant operation in 1988, and died of a heart attack on 5 August 1995 in Karachi.</h3>
<a id-'tribute-link' target='_blank' href='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agha_Hasan_Abedi'>More Info</a>
</main>
```

Comment: I just added some space between the two elements and now I can edit the positioning of the text as well.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the name of the element from caption to h3, perhaps the name was the issue but this change now allows me to write directions that now works. Thanks for the suggestions to use the figure element tag. Will try it out.